At graphical login, I'd like to simply start X
On my notebook I'm using OpenSuse Tumbleweed.
When the system boots, I'm presented with a login screen and I have three different options for three different sessions: Plasma on X, Icewm (on X) and Plasma on Wayland.
Should I install another desktop environment (e.g., Gnome) I'd expect that the login screen would show me Gnome as a fourth option.
Is it possible to add another option to enable me to just (re)start X, that in turn executes ~/.xsession, that in turn starts the different utilities and eventually a window manager?

There are different methods to start another X server, I want to replace the server on which the login screen is displayed with another one.

Can you just type ctl-alt-F2 or similar to get a new VT text terminal?

@meuh I'd prefer not to

For
achlinux
they seem to suggest you just need to add a my.desktop file in the right
place. The
xinit-session package
they use is just that and a shell script, Download snapshot
tar.gz.
Perhaps that works for OpenSuse?
